# RESTful Speech to Text Service

Tags: objective-c, json, rest, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm looking for a RESTful Speech to Text service for iOS that will allow me to attach an audio file to a `POST` request (with an API like `AFNetworking`), then receive a text response of the translated text. The AT&T API for Speech to Text seems interesting, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation about working with Objective-C.

Are there any such services, free/paid, that would offer the ability to "translate" an audio file into text through a `POST` request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the Nexiwave API? I've heard some pretty great stuff about it. http://nexiwave.com/index.php/site-map/119-integrate-voicemail-to-text-in-5-minutes

Answer (score 0):

One option is using Google Chrome API.
Refer to http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/

You can recognize using flac(or speex)-encoded *audio recording*.

I don't know whether it's free or not for commercial product. But you can use it for testing and development purpose.

Comment: Google Api can not be used for commercial product as it is not public API

Answer (score 0):

Try Nexiwave.com. API is here: http://nexiwave.com/index.php/site-map/119-integrate-voicemail-to-text-in-5-minutes

Answer (score 0):

at&t is free/Paid Api and you can make 3 apps for free in at&t you need to post audio and you will get json,Xml in response 
https://developer.att.com/apis/speech/docs contain documentation for it.

Also there is another APi http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/mobile-applications/dragon-dictation/index.htm  it's a paid API but as you register you will get API-Key and other key required to make sample application(only for development not for production).

but no one API is accurate as google and siri. 
I have made sample application using at&t API,Dragon mobile API and Google.If you have any doubt feel free to ask